# CommandTimeout being ignored using DbDataAdapter.Fill

Tags: c#, connection-timeout, command-timeout, sqldatadapter

I cannot seem to get the CommandTimeout to work in the code below.  I set the timeout value to 1 second just to test to ensure it works but it seems to be ignored.  The SELECT statement takes about 15 seconds to run and it runs to completion.  I am expecting a timeout exception to occur after 1 second.  I have searched the internet to find an example of how to do this and I have not been able to find anything.  What am I doing wrong?

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();
command.Connection = factory.CreateConnection();
command.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=;Password=****";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
command.CommandTimeout = 1;

using (DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter())
{
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I wrote a SELECT command that takes longer than 30 seconds to run.  This also does not timeout.  I even commented out my CommandTimeout line and it still ran to completion.  So, it seems that even the default CommandTimeout of 30 seconds is being ignored.  I am stumped...any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I think I might have figured it out.  It seems when I wrote a really complex SELECT statement the command timeout exception occurred.  I can only guess that what is happening it that, with my simple SELECT command, it is taking less than 1 second to execute the command but then it takes an additional 15 seconds to load the data set.  Am I on the right track here?  Does this seem likely?

Answer (score 0):

The Command Timeout is the cumulative time-out (for all network packets that are read during the invocation of a method) for all network reads during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user processing time, only network read time.

For example, with a 30 second time out, if Read requires two network packets, then it has 30 seconds to read both network packets. If you call Read again, it will have another 30 seconds to read any data that it requires.

NOTE:
CommandTimeout has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string) or if being used during asynchronous method calls such as BeginExecuteReader.

Comment: Note: this is taken verbatim from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2